# How do I perform a case-sensitive search using LIKE?

Tags: sql-server-2008, pattern-matching, sql-like, collate

I'm trying to find records that contain a string of 6 or more alpha-numeric characters in uppercase.  Some examples:

```
PENDING  3RDPARTY  CODE27
```

I'm using the following statement:

```
SELECT Details
FROM MyTable
WHERE Details LIKE '%[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]%';
```

This is returning all records that contain any 6-or-more-letter word, regardless of case.

I've added a `COLLATE` statement:

```
SELECT Details
FROM MyTable
WHERE Details COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]%';
```

This changes nothing.  It still returns records with 6-or-more-letter word, regardless of case.

Just as a test, I tried:

```
SELECT Details
FROM MyTable
WHERE Details COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%pending%';

SELECT Details
FROM MyTable
WHERE Details COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%PENDING%';
```

Both of these worked, returning records containing "pending" and "PENDING" respectively.  So the issue seems to by the `LIKE` claus's pattern matching.

What can I do to perform this case-sensitive search?

Comment: try using COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try using `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` rather than `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`

Answer (score 35):

**Update due to @GeraldSv**: Use collation `Latin1_General_BIN`

```
SELECT Details
FROM MyTable
WHERE Details 
LIKE '%[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]%' 
COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

You need to place the collation specifier *after* the string to be matched rather than the column:

```
SELECT Details
FROM MyTable
WHERE Details 
LIKE '%[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]%' 
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Update: While my answer above is correct, there is a bug filed at Connect: [Case-SENSITIVITY doesn't work when using a range in like with COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/725949/case-sensitivity-doesnt-work-when-using-a-range-in-like-with-collate-latin1-general-cs-as) which Microsoft have marked as 'By Design".

I verified by using AdventureWorks2008R2 (case insensitive, out of the box default), in the Person.Person table I changed 3 last names ending in 'n' to 'N', and then ran the following queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName LIKE '%N' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Success. Return 3 rows as expected.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName LIKE '%[N]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Success. Return 3 rows as expected.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName LIKE '%[N-N]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Success. Return 3 rows as expected.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName LIKE '%[M-N]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Fails. Returns 3334 Rows   (which is all Lastname's ending in 'n' and 'N')

Update: Thanks to @GeraldSv, this works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName LIKE '%[M-N]' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: Thanks for all the research!

Answer (score 2):

I use the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS != upper(LastName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```